# Simulating the number of contract to maintain constant value

Tags: python, r, sas, simulation, modeling

I have a set of say 10,000 contracts ( Loan account numbers). The contracts are for specific durations say 24,48,84 months. My pool consists of a mix of these contracts for a different duration. Assume that at the start of this month I have 100 contracts amounting to 10,000 USD . After 2 months a few accounts/contracts are closed prematurely (early pay off) and few are extended. I need to simulate the data to maintain a constant value (amount of 10,000 USD). It means I need to know how many new contracts that I need to add say 2 months from now so that the value of my portfolio remains at 10,000 USD. Can someone help me if there is any technique to **simulate** this? Preferably in R, Python or SAS

Answer (score 0):

Add a payoff date element to each contract object. Then, do:

```
need = 0
for c in contracts:
    need += int( (date today + 2 mo) > c.payoff_date or c.paid_off == True)
print 10000 - len(contracts) + need
```

Comment: Anyway to simulat this? I have made some amend to the original problem

Comment: I can assist further, but need to see a best-effort bit of sample code. I don’t do free contract work, which is what this sounds like.